# Press key to a specific process

Tags: process, keypress

I want to write a small application that can press keys on different process.
The different process is a console application - but I want to run it in a hidden mode and specifically simulate the "Pause/Break" key-press on it (same as if it was focused and I pressed the pause key manually)

I've found those examples:
[How can I programmatically generate keypress events in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1645815/1726419)
[How to simulate key presses on a specific application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55448466/how-to-simulate-key-presses-on-a-specific-application)

but I think they can't assist in my situation (or maybe I'm wrong?)

as for programming language - I don't much care - (c#/c++/c/python/ruby - whatever will do the job)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're storing your processes in some variables/handlers.

All you need to do is get the input stream of your process and send the key that you want to pass/press for the specific process.

your code should look something like this:

```
    Process p = new Process(); //your process
    string key = "A"; //character or string that you want to press
    p.StandardInput.Write(key);
```

Where 'P' is the process and key is the pressed key.

Hope this helps!